# Is it possible to use the same domain for API Gateway and Static S3 bucket behind a Cloudfront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently creating a feedback app in AWS. I have the backend in Lambda which is connected to API Gateway and the frontend of it is served by a Static S3 bucket behind a Cloudfront distribution.

I would like to enable TLS 1.2 on the API Gateway, however, this only seems possible via Cloudfront. I also want to be able to serve it on the same domain name but a different path as the S3 bucket. Currently, the S3 bucket sits on feedback.domain.com. I did have a custom dodmain hooked up to the API Gateway on api.feedback.domain.com, which would work when I made requests to it via Postman. However, when I made requests via the JavaScript on the S3 bucket pages, it would never work and I'd get a CORS error. I am happy to use this if more viable but I would need to ask another question about CORS.

I would like to get the API Gateway to sit on feedback.domain.com/api, because as far as I know, using the same domain as the page making the request should overcome CORS. I've tried the below setup but cannot get this to work.
[image: aws2]

When I browse to feedback.domain.com/api, I get the error page I set up in Cloudfront. I've tried creating an invalidation so it has cleared the cache on the Cloudfront distribution, but this hasn't changed anything.

I modified the setup so the S3 bucket's origin path was /web/* however i then proceed to get AccessDenied errors everywhere
Setup:
[image]

Thank you in advance to anyone that can offer their wise wisdom :)

UPDATE:

Below are my Cloudwatch Logs for the API stage. I go to feedback.domain.com/api, get a 403 error with my custom error page defined in Cloudfront, but no log in Cloudwatch: [image]

Here are behaviours:
[image]

API behaviour:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Current origin setup:
[image]

[image]

A note to @Caldazar, You mention 403 means I'm hitting the API, however, if I go to a none-valid url, feedback.domain.com/IDoNotExist I still get a 403 error. I believe this is something to do with S3?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `Origin path`.

The `Origin path` value is actually what will be appended to your request when it's sent to the origin. For example, a request to `https://example.com/api/test` would result in a request being sent to `https://example.com/api/*/api/test`

For API Gateway, your `Origin path` should be your API stage, for example `/dev`, `/prod`...

You should create additional `behavior` that would have Path pattern `/api/*` and `Origin` set to your `API origin` that you created above.

Since you would have `/api/` in your path, this wouldn't be matched properly to the path you have in `API Gateway`. To deal with that, you should add a `CloudFront Function` to your `API behavior` created above as part of the `Viewer request`. `CloudFront Functions` are at the bottom of the `Edit behavior` page. This function should change `/api` to `/`. This is code that works for me for such situations:

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;

    // Check whether the URI starts with "api"
    if (uri.startsWith('/api/')) {
        request.uri = uri.replace('/api/', '/');
    }

    return request;
}
```

Edit based on new details:

In order to hit the API, you cannot go to `/api`. You behaviour is set to forward to `API Gateway` only if your path is `/api/*` which means, only if you go to a URL like `feedback.domain.com/api/mymethod`.

As for the second part, S3 will return 403 code if a file does not exist, because there's a possibility that a file actually exists, but your user does not have permission to see the file.

Comment: Hi @Caldazar thank you for the reply. I have followed all your steps but I am getting a 403 error of feedback.domain.com/api. My understanding is that anything that goes to feedback.domain.com/api should be “going” to fjwyXXXXX.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/fbk

When I go to fjwyXXXXX.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/fbk I get a response from my API, but not on feedback.domain.com/api. Do I need to change the path pattern on the S3 bucket, it's set to Default (*), the API origin's behaviour is set to /api/* with the function linked that you put above

Comment: 403 would mean that you managed to hit the API, but not the correct path for your function. Do you have API access logs in place? Did you remove `Origin path` from your origins? Can you put updated screenshots (Origins, Behaviors, API stage)?

Comment: Hi Caldazar, please see updated info above :)

Comment: Hi @Caldazar, many thanks for the reply. So based on what you are saying, if I go to feedback.domain.com/api/methodname should I get a reply from api gateway as opposed to S3?

Comment: That's right, Nathan